# AWS Glue: ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'data_transformations_app'

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-glue

I am running an ETL glue job on AWS.
It refers to a folder in S3 that contains the main function in a zip file.
The path is correct, I have checked it multiple times.
For some reason I keep getting this error:

> ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'data_transformations_app'

The error logs show that it successfully downloads the correct buckets (jar files) and has the correct file path.

I tried changing
'from data_transformations_app import main'
to just
'import main'
and I get the same error.
I downloaded the zip file and checked the main.py file.

Answer (score 0):

Confirm that the zip file structure is correct The `main.py` should be at the root of the zip file, not in a subdirectory. For example, if your module is `data_transformations_app`, the structure should be:

```
data_transformations_app.zip
└── main.py
```

Not this:

```
data_transformations_app.zip
└── data_transformations_app
    └── main.py
```